# Анимация в Windows Forms

Tags: c#

Хотел бы сделать анимацию того, как элипс переходит справа налево. И, как в змейке, когда дойдёт до левой стенки, должен пройти через неё и выйти через правую стенку. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно обойтись двумя эллипсами, и как только 1ый ( тот что справа, видимый на форме) будет выходить за экран справа на N пикселей, то 2ой эллипс, до этого пока еще не видимый т.к. имеет пока Х координату меньше 0, на N пикселей появляется от левой границы, т.к. по факту на форме постоянно только 1 эллипс находиться. В одном цикле можно сделать.